# FreeSWITCH: Call one number, then connect it to another?

Tags: freeswitch

I'd like to have FreeSWITCH behave the following way:

- I dial a destination number on my soft phone.
- FreeSWITCH calls my cell phone.
- Once answered, FreeSWITCH then connects that call to the originally dialed number.

I've played a little bit with bridging and conferences, but I'm relatively new to FreeSWITCH so I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

here I described the scenario which is similar to what you want: http://txlab.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/fight-the-roaming-costs-with-freeswitch/